# Typekit fonts not working on some machines

Tags: typekit

We're using typekit fonts for some of our styles. We've noticed that on some machines, the fonts don't load on our live site, although they do on our dev site. This is only on certain machines, and only when viewing our live site (which is identical code-wise to dev at this point.)

For example, my boss looks at the dev site and the live site in two separate tabs in Chrome on the Mac. The elements using typekit fonts look different on the live site (they're failing over to the default serif font.) On my Mac in Chrome, everything is correct on both versions of the site.

Is there some kind of browser setting somewhere that would cause this? (Given that the fonts being used are barely distinguishable from a default serif font, my solution would be to just eliminate the typekit fonts altogether, but it's not my call to make.)

Comment: On the machine that didn't work, was it running Firefox? If yes, it might be related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/8777877/583539.

Comment: Just want to clarify one thing: did it ever work on your live site? If it never worked (i.e. only worked on the dev site), you might want to check the "Kit Settings" on your typekit account and add the live site domain in there.

Comment: Yes, they have worked on the live site. The domain is listed in our typekit account.

Comment: I'm having this same issue! Tried cache busting the typekit js, but that hasn't helped. I've got a message into support@typekit.com, but no reply this friday. Anyone else experience this?

Comment: Having the issue on an iOS device and another computer, but locally and on my machine I'm not experiencing the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this solves your issue, but my issue was that I was loading "Museo Sans", and I needed to load "museo-sans" for the css font-family. The first font-family was loading the font directly from my machine, so it worked on another designers machine who also had the font loaded, but not on most other devices/machines via typekit file.

Hope this clears up one potential scenario.